# Frobenius norm minimization with inequality constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, normed-spaces, linear-programming, matrix-calculus

Let $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}$, $B \in \mathbb R^{n\times r}$, $X \in \mathbb R^{m\times r}$, and $Y\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$. Let $\|\cdot\|_F$ be the Frobenius norm of a matrix. How can we solve the following optimization problem in $X \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$?

$$\begin{array}{ll} \min_{_{X,B}} & \|A-BX^\top\|^2_F\\ \text{subject to} & \text{Tr}(Y^\top(A-BX^\top))\leq 0\end{array}$$

Can this problem be solved in closed form?

Are there some references to solving the inequality constrained linear least Frobenius norm problems?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you are showing only one side of the supposed constraint.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I forgot the inequality. Now it's fixed, thanks!

Comment: That an be solved as a linearly-constrained linear least squares problem, for which there is available software under numerous computing environments. Modeling front-ends, such as with CVX, YALMIP, CVXPY, CVXR, adn others, can accept the matrix variable as is, saving you the trouble and error-propensity of vec'ing the matrix.

Comment: I know there is software for solving this problem but, as stated in my question, I am looking for a closed-form solution. I think it is possible for this problem. I will try to sketch an answer with my findings.

Comment: The only 'closed form solution" I can think of is to solve the linear least squares problem, ignroing the constraint. If that solution satisfies the constraint, then it is the solution to the original constrained problem. But if not, you will not have the solution to the original problem.

Comment: I was formulating the problem in terms of the dual, then you get that the lagrangian is the objective - \lambda times the scalar constraint (with \lambda as lagrange multiplier). By differentiating and imposing the KKT (strong duality holds since the problem is convex and the slater's condition holds) we can get the solution for the primal.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone do you think that may work?

Comment: If the unconstrained solution satisfies the constraint, yes. If not, no.